# Realm update of one-to-many relation

Tags: android, database, realm, one-to-many, realm-list

I have 2 classes:

```
public class DbFile extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String fileId;
    // getters and setters
}

public class DbNews extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long newsId;
    private RealmList<DbFile> photos;
    // getters and setters
}
```

When user pulls data from the server I'd like to create a new DbNews entity if not exists, or update existing one.

```
public void addNews(ApiNews news) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
        DbNews inDb = newsById(news.getId());

        if (inDb == null) {
            inDb = r.createObject(DbNews.class, news.getId());
        }

        inDb.setPhotos(FileListMerger.mergeWithRemote(r, inDb.getPhotos(), news.getPhotos()));

        r.copyToRealmOrUpdate(inDb);
    });
    realm.close();
}
```

Here `mergeWithRemote` function looks like this

```
public static RealmList<DbFile> mergeWithRemote(Realm realm, @NonNull RealmList<DbFile> local, @NonNull List<File> remote) {
    Set<String> remoteIds = new HashSet<>();
    for (File file : remote) {
        remoteIds.add(file.getId());
    }

    Set<String> localIds = new HashSet<>();
    for (DbFile file : local) {
        localIds.add(file.getFileId());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < local.size(); i++) {
        if (!remoteIds.contains(local.get(i).getFileId())) {
            local.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < remote.size(); i++) {
        if (!localIds.contains(remote.get(i).getId())) {
            DbFile newPhoto = realm.where(DbFile.class).equalTo("fileId", remote.get(i).getId()).findFirst();
            if (newPhoto == null) {
                newPhoto = realm.createObject(DbFile.class, remote.get(i).getId());
            }
            local.add(newPhoto);
        }
    }

    return local;
}
```

From my point of view this should work fine. But when I get the news by id from realm, I'm getting a news without photos (`news.getPhotos().size() == 0`).

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
DbNews news = realm.where(DbNews.class)
                .equalTo("newsId", newsId).findFirst()
// somewhere later
realm.close();
```

NOTE: when I open the database in RealmBrowser I see files saved in Files table, and news saved in News table, but news contains empty list of files.

Comment: You are opening Realm instances that you never close, this can cause Realms on background threads to become retained on outdated versions where the newly inserted data does not exist yet outside of transactions. What thread is this on?

Comment: Yeah, I know about the `close()` method. Everything is on the same background thread.

Comment: But you are opening an instance you will never close in this line `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(DbNews.class)` and here `Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(`

Comment: I understand. I mean closing the instance doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: How is `newsById(...)` implemented? How is `setPhotos(..)` implemented?  You know you're passing in a managed `RealmList<DbFile>` to `mergeWithRemote(..)` and changing it by calling `add(..)` and `remove(..)` on it?